# Exclude file from Typescript compile effect into one output JS in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a typescript project which I compile to a single file with VS. Everything works fine, but there is one library that I already have in the target environment and since it's 3000lines I want to exclude it from compiling to the output file. Unfortunately this library is not a d.ts file, simply .ts one. Is there a way to exclude it from compilation?

UPDATE:
I added tsconfig.json file. It does not exclude file that I want to be excluded. Is this because it is referenced in other file? My congif.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"outFile": "../pathTo/my/otuputFile.js",
"outDir": "./pathTo/my/",
"removeComments": false
},

"files": [
"../allmy/files/lsited.ts"
],
"exclude": [
"libraryIdontwant.ts"
]
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json` add it to the exclude array

```json
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts",

    "path/to/the/file.ts"
]
```

Comment: unfortunately in the end it does not work, I rushed with marking your answer. I updated my question